# How to calculate the size of transport package of a bundle from Content Manager side?

Tags: cme

How to calculate the size of transport package of a bundle from Content Manager side.

Before I start publishing the bundle, I need to know what could be the size of my transport package of bundle?

Comment: I'm curious to know what the business reason for this is. Can you share the full use case please?

Comment: The most common use case for this is when there are restrictions on package sizes for transport/deployer. You could very easily create a bundle with over 1GB by adding the "right" pages and components to it. See also: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12426/calculate-package-size-when-an-item-is-added-to-bundle

Answer (score 4):

The process of publishing involves several stages: resolving, rendering, transport to deployer, deployment, commit of deployment.

If you need to know the size before starting deployment, then you could just write a deployer or storage extension to look at the size of the package zip file in the incoming directory.

If you need to know the size before transport begins, you could possibly implement a custom renderer extension that appends the size of each rendered item to a running variable which you could store in App Data perhaps.

If you want to know the size before starting rendering, you would need to do it based on some kind of an estimate, e.g. total size of binaries for all resolved items plus the approximate size of the resolved items markup or dd4t model. You could probably come up with a formula for this based on the size of the item (component). You'd need to be creative with this formula and go based on some historical average or median package sizes.

If you want to know before you start resolving, well, that's going to be tough because you won't even know the amount of items to resolve (remember that each item in the bundle could have related and embedded/linked items). You could again throw an average based formula against it just as an estimate based on the number of top level items in the bundle.

Comment: very well explained!